# Does a stepper motor's error accumulate?

Tags: stepper-motor

I am trying to understand the concept of stepper motor error.  A typical Nema17 stepper takes 1.8 degree steps and has an accuracy of +/-5%.

Consider the diagram below:

[image: stepper plate]

In the diagram, 4 stepper motors each coupled to lead screws are being controlled to vertically lift a rectangular plane.  If we command all 4 steppers to begin to rotate and the lead screws are infinitely long will the plane being lifted become increasing unlevel with time?

Comment: Well, there's still a known number of steps per revolution...

Comment: @Hearth correct. So after the controller has requested 100,000 steps from each stepper will the plate be as level as it was after 1,000 steps?

Comment: An ideally set up stepper, if not going too fast and no excessive load, will not lose steps the whole time it is powered up, so no accumulated error.

Comment: Yeah, only to be ideal you need to take hell of a margin both in the stepper size and the drive current. And to only work slow. Really in 2021 you should only take BLDC for applications where losing steps matters

Comment: If the probability of single failure of single device (e.g. a missed step) is not zero, then the average number of failures in the course of N steps will grow as N grows. That's just math. Whether those accumulated failures are distributed evenly arcoss all 4 motors, is another question. Most likely, uneven load (you can't make it absolutely even, right?) would mean slightly different probability of failure of each motor. I wouldn't be surprised if they piled up on one motor more than on its siblings.

Comment: As the answer says - use an encoder.  Even if this works on day one, eventually you will have debris buildup, component wear, etc, that increases the torque load and the steppers will, at some point, start skipping.  Without an encoder you won't detect this happening.

Comment: Even if your steppers are behaving perfectly, eventually you'll run into issues with the tolerance on the pitch of your lead screws.

Comment: @IgorG the answer seems to indicate that this is not true (error will not accumulate).  The 5% error is in the angular distance between each step, but 200 steps must equal precisely 360 degrees.  We can assume that each step will be 1.89-1.71 degrees (5% error) and say steps 1-100 were 1.89 and steps 101-200 were 1.71 we would still have stepped precisely 360 degrees after a complete rotation.  Therefore after infinite complete rotations we should have the same error as 10 complete rotations.  Assuming lead screw is perfect ..etc.

Comment: As a complete aside, a better solution here might be to use a single, cheaper, larger motor and just couple the other four axes to the driven one with a timing belt or chain.  This lets you use a less precise motor to drive all four shafts and the timing belt connection ensures that they all turn synchronously.  You can then set up stop-stations with simple limit switches along the way.  If you need continuous indexing, the same arrangement with a single, larger, stepper or servo is still an attractive idea - less complexity and fewer things to manage in case of faults.

Comment: @J... this is a good point I do believe fewer motors would reduce complexity and ensure better synchronization.  But can only keep this in mind for future projects, as I am too far along at this point.  What I need are some ultra precise nema 17s for this project.

Comment: @Feynman137, validity of any conclusion heavily depends on validity of assumptions. Why are you assuming that 200 controlling pulses will always result in a complete rotation? My interpretation of the answer is: your controlling device needs some feedback on whether a stepper has actually missed a step (e.g. an encoder), and adjust controlling pulses to keep the platform level.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A stepper motor rotates in discrete steps. You command it to rotate one step at a time. A NEMA-17 motor has 200 such steps to a revolution. If you rotate the shaft yourself you can feel the locations of each of the 200 steps.

The locations of the steps are fixed inside the motor, so after 200 steps the shaft has rotated 360 degrees. The angle between the location within the motor of any particular step N and N+1 may have up to 5% error, but since the sum of the angles between each step add up to 360 you'll be back to where you started from after 200 steps.

The datasheet includes the 5% error figure so that you know how evenly the steps are positioned around the circle.

The biggest problem with stepper motors is that they can miss a step. That is, the motor is at position N and after you command it to step it fails to move to position N+1. This is usually due to the load on the motor being too large -- the motor doesn't have enough torque to move to the next step with the load. This may also be caused by trying to step the motor too fast.

In your table scenario the table can become uneven if one or more of the motors misses a step. Usually, however, if a motor is able to move one step it is able to move through all 200 steps in the cycle if the load doesn't change.

The most common way to detect if a stepper motor has missed a step is to use an optical encoder which can be used to determine the position of the shaft.

Comment: The angle between the location within the motor of any particular step N and N+1 may have up to 5% error, but since the sum of the angles between each step add up to 360 you'll be back to where you started from after 200 steps.

Comment: If you miss a step while moving relatively fast, there is no guarantee that the motor will even pick up the speed again, can get stuck.

Comment: with stepper motors it is extremely helpful to implement a constant acceleration algorithm. Practically this means that the pulses are widely spaced when starting from rest, and get more frequent until some desired maximum is reached. As F=mA this keeps the force required from the motor at some manageable and more or less constant level, as long as the load does not change much. I've done this successfully by using a look up table which was generated with a python script, using equations derived from this article. https://www.embedded.com/generate-stepper-motor-speed-profiles-in-real-time/

Comment: @GregoryKornblum Indeed. This phenomenon is known as a "stall" - the stepper indexer in this state is still commanding rotation of the motor and the magnetic field continues to rotate but the speed of the field rotation is high enough that the rotor can no longer follow it and it comes to a stop.  The telltale for this condition is that the motor continues to emit the typical coil whine of at-speed operation but the shaft remains motionless.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum: From my experience, unless a stepper motor is being used slowly enough that it would have time to start and stop with each step, *most* missed steps will result in stall conditions.  Steppers don't really have an operating mode where they occasionally slip.  If a motor's driven phase never lags its position by more than half of a full cycle, it will catch up without missing any pulses.  If the phase lags by more than that, the motor will start being driven sometimes backward and sometimes forward, yielding a net useful torque of essentially zero.

Comment: Well, i don't think motor has to stop at each step, i mean, i know for a fact that's not the intended use. But for me even the possibility of a slip or stall is bad enough to stay away from steppers. A closed loop stepper is another thing, but anyway for all my applications i use bldc.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum: Of course stepper motors are often used in situations where they don't stop between steps, but in such situations any slippage will cause them to lose traction completely.  A bigger issue I see with regard to the choice between stepper and BLDC motor is that stepper motors generally don't mind being powered for the purpose of producing holding torque, while BLDC motors aren't designed for such usage.  I would think a combination of BLDC and holding brake would be ideal, but I don't know of such devices.

Comment: You know, holding torque doesn't generate work, only heat. With bldc the servo keeps it standing, while in stepper a kind of a control loop by the holding current. It only creates torque when rotor is displaced, so in this regard its not different than a PID loop. Only burns power when standing.